# Configure Tailwind css with micro-frontend architecture using nrwl/nx angular apps

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend, nrwl

How to configure tailwind css with micro-frontend using @nrwl/nx library. Few steps that I know are

```
npx nx generate @nrwl/angular:setup-tailwind <App name>

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

This generator adds the tailwind.config.js file to your project. It also generated the tailwind imports in your global stylesheet file. Usually, that is okay, when you are running a monolith, but since the global stylesheet of a micro frontend is not exposed, we have to find a solution to include the tailwind styles in the exposed chunk of the micro frontend.

In the `module-federation.config.js` I have set the below code

```
const coreLibraries = new Set([
  ..............
  'tailwindcss',
  'postcss',
  'autoprefixer',
]);

module.exports = {
  shared: (libraryName, defaultConfig) => {
    if (coreLibraries.has(libraryName)) {
      return defaultConfig;
    }

    return false;
  },
};
```

However, the tailwind scss is not working across all the micro-frontends

Comment: I found this article few weeks ago. It uses proxy pattern to expose the stylesheet. https://ng-journal.com/blog/2022-12-02-tailwind-and-module-federation/

Comment: Although I would probably just go to use tailwind separately with each micro frontend. Because you can keep view encapsulation and developers have more control on the styles.

Comment: @RicardoSilva If we use tailwind for each micro-frontend, then there might be multiple load for CSS. It should load only once isn't it?

Comment: You are right, but that mean anyone using new utilities or any arbitrary variant will not work if they don't bundle and deploy the whole host every time some child app changes. And the footprint is really small. But it can be made even smaller. By putting the base in the host and adding the CSS to each remote/child app, will still cache the resource but all letting each child app use its own compilation of utilities. and purge can even eliminate the utilities that are already coming from the host if you want, question is the how and if is worth investing time for that sort of integration.

Comment: Maybe you can consider to create an UI Kit as a package to share between MFEs so you can keep design guidelines through the teams. It's also good to keep dependencies isolated so you can limit faults only on specific module.